# React Native: How to check if geolocation permission has been granted

Tags: react-native, permissions, react-native-ios

I know I can request geolocation permission on iOS with React Native as such:

```
await navigator.geolocation.requestAuthorization()
```

However, how do I know if user has granted the permission or not? The function above returns nothing.

I would like to avoid using a third party library just to do this as in this answer:
[Determining if geolocation enabled with react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371987/determining-if-geolocation-enabled-with-react-native)

The most popular Permissions 3rd party library hasn't been updated in 10 months and has no support for latest versions of React Native.

Answer (score 0):

This is all I could figure out: https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/geolocation-permissions

So, the function will look like this:

```
checkPermission = () => {
  navigator.geolocation
  .getCurrentPosition(
    () => this.setState({permission: 'GRANTED'}),
    () => this.setState({permission: 'DENIED'})
  );
}
```

This can be either invoked in some action or e.g. in `componentDidMount`.

And if you need to redirect user to allow access to location in settings, see my other example: https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/open-app-settings where code line:

`Linking.openURL("app-settings:");`

does the trick.

Comment: This will crash without invoking `navigator.geolocation.requestAuthorization()` first. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605192/react-native-crash-while-requesting-permissions?noredirect=1#comment94073317_53605192

Comment: @etayluz hmm, ok. I tested that expo example on my device (iPhone Xs, iOS 12.x) and it worked as expected without `requestAuthorization()`.

Comment: Expo? Who said anything about expo?

Comment: I meant Expo "snack", not the library :)

Comment: I'm running React Native 0.57.5 ejected. Expo has their own little magic with their SDK - it's not the real React Native

Answer (score 0):

I have used geolocation from the react-native-geolocation-service package to solve this for ios and android

```
const getLocationServicesStatus = async () => {try {
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  const locationStatus = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
  );
  return locationStatus === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED;
}

if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
  const locationStatus = await geolocation.requestAuthorization(
    'whenInUse',
  );
  return locationStatus === 'granted';
}

return null } catch (error) {
logger.warn('Error checking location status:', error);
return null;
```

}
};